# How to insert timeseries in Cassandra table

Tags: cassandra

I would like to make a Query as "Give me the values of id_sensor on 5/5/2017 between 8 am and 6 pm" I have the sensor_id(punto_muestreo) in df image, I have defined the table as follows:

```
  session.execute(
"""
CREATE TABLE magnitude_by_day (
punto_muestreo text, 
fecha date,
df_horas time,
value float,
PRIMARY KEY ((punto_muestreo,fecha),df_horas)
) 
"""
```

)

The problem is that i dont know how to fill the table to get a timeseries. I attach an image of my df. The columns H1,H2..H24. are the values per hour from 1 to 24 hours.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxSb7.png

[The columns H1,H2..H24. are the values per hour from 1 to 24 hours.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxSb7.png)

Comment: Please review the guidelines here to understand how to ask question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please add comments to the fields with their english meaning  -  not everybody knows Spanish ;-)